# Unable to access Liferay 6.2 on dedicated windows cloud server

Tags: windows, networking, liferay, liferay-6

We install liferay6.2 in windows dedicated server 2008 r2. Liferay sever is working smoothly in the server but when we are trying to access it from browser then we are unable to access it. Error: server not found. In Liferay we have one portlet for video conference and it is also working fine. We can access the server through RDP(Remote Desktop) but whenever trying to access through browser fail to find the server in web.

May be this issue can be easily handle by the network admin or may be by any Liferay developer.

Answer (score 0):

Does your dedicated server have a public (routed) IP address? Also, check firewalls that might block port 8080 if you have not changed the default port. As you say Liferay is running smoothly - you just can't access it - your problem is most likely rather related to the network configuration, not to Liferay itself

Comment: Yes that was the problem of server. The solution is that we have to set the range of ports in instance of the server in security option. As I am not the network admin that's why we faced that problem.